# Additional auth tables when extending Djangos AbstractUser

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I am new to Django and discovered something I do not quite understand: I extended the default user class of django auth with a custom field to look like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    business_entity = models.ForeignKey('BusinessEntity', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

In the settings file, I also added the needed `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.User'` since my new user model is located in the core app. Works fine so far.

After applying all migrations (even after wiping the database and reapplying), I, however, am left with a few additional tables that I did not want to create and that seem not to be used by Django's auth app:
[Tables created after migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgcDu.png)

As you can see there are from the auth app: auth_group, auth_group_permissions and auth_permissions as well as from core app: core_user_groups, core_user_user_permissions.

I searched quite a while - maybe with the wrong keywords? - but I am not able to figure out if I need all those tables and - especially - what the additional core tables are used for. Can you shed some light on this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: They are from `django.contrib.auth` and some are for the `ManyToManyField`s in the models (For instance `core_user_groups` is prefixed core because it is a m2m in the `AbstractUser` and hence your user model also has it). See [Using the Django authentication system (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/) for more details.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, I did not think about the ManyToManyFields needing additional tables. Thanks for your anwer!

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure those are the tables that django uses to store permissions and you shouldn't delete them. For instance, when you make a superuser (an admin), django knows that only he/she can access the `/admin` page. This knowledge comes from permissions stored in those tables.

If you are not using those tables chances are they only occupy a minimum amount of space (according to the link below, only 4 permissions are added by default) and you shouldn't worry about them. That said, knowing how to manage permissions well can help a lot depending on your project.

More info about permissions can be seen [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, it makes perfect sense, that Django needs those tables for the Many2ManyField once I start assigning single permissions to a user. Thanks for clearing that up!